# JPA Spring - Filter Date

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, autowired

Is it possible to filter the date? For example i just want to select the data of the last 30 days? 
The selection should be between now and now - 30 days. 
I would prefere a solution without a query.

```
@Service 
public class PersonService { 

   @Autowired 
   private PersonRepository personRepository;         
   public Stream<Person> all(Person mysearch){ 
       return personRepository 
              .findAll(Example.of(mysearch)) 
              .stream() 
              .map(Person::fromPerson); 
  } 
}
```

Class Person:

```
public class Person { 

    public Integer index; 
    public String firstname; 
    public String lastname; 
    @JsonFormat(pattern="dd.MM.yyyy") 
    public Date exdate; 
    public String insnr; 

    private Person(Integer index, String firstname, String lastname, Date exdate, String insnr){ 
        this.index=index; 
        this.firstname=firstname; 
        this.lastname=lastname; 
        this.exdate=exdate; 
        this.insnr=insnr; 
    } 

    public static Person fromPerson(Person person){ 
        return person == null ? null : new Person(person.getIndex(), person.getFirstname(), person.getLastname(), person.getExdate(), person.getInsnr()); 
    } 
}
```

Controller:

```
@Autowired 
   private PersonService personService; 
   @RequestMapping(value="/person/list/**") 
   public List<Person> loadPersonList(   
                   @RequestParam(value = "insnr" ,required=false) String insnr) throws ParseException {         
       mysearch.setInsnr(insnr); 
       return personService.all(mysearch).collect(Collectors.toList()); 
   }
```

Comment: what did you mean `data of the last 30 days` ?

Comment: Could you provide more data to support your question?
What are the data members of Person class?

Comment: Sure. Define a query, and execute it.

Comment: In Person there is the field exdate and when I search for a person, I just want to get those where the date is between now and now - 30 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(dateInstance);
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -30);
Date dateBefore30Days = cal.getTime();    
 public Stream<Person> all(Person mysearch){ 
       return personRepository 
              .findAll(Example.of(mysearch)).stream().filter(person -> person.getExdate().compareTo(dateBefore30Days) > 0)
                .map(Person::fromPerson)                       
                .findAny()
                .orElse(""); }
```

Answer (score 5):

Spring JPA repositories support *GreaterThan* keyword [queries](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods).

You could consider something like :

```
LocalDate dateBefore30Days = LocalDate.now().minusDays(30);

List<Person> persons =  personRepository.findByExdateGreaterThan(dateBefore30Days);
```